# Changing Java program LookAndFeel doesn't affect

Tags: java, look-and-feel

I'm trying to change LAF of my program in this way:

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainWin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

But this doesn't affect and program still looks as METAL while this reports "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel" that means it must be changed:

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getClass().getName();
```

Changing to other LAFs has the same problem!
What's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu); I got avilable LAFs list in program and I know Metal,Nimbus,Motif and GTK+ are available!

Comment: What do you mean by: while this reports "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel" that means it must be changed? What is 'this', and what must be changed?

Comment: I mean the code below that sentence! problem fixed . thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you set look and feel before you create your GUI? Because if your GUI is already created (even if not shown), you have to tell Swing that LAF was updated:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

GTKLookAndFeel only gets applied if the operating system is Linux.

Using GTKLookAndFeel for a application running on Windows does not change the Look and Feel.
It will still display the Metal Look and Feel.

> Note: The GTK+ L&F will only run on UNIX or Linux systems with GTK+
>   2.2 or later installed, while the Windows L&F runs only on Windows
>   systems. Like the Java (Metal) L&F, the Motif L&F will run on any
>   platform.

More info on [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://Modifying%20the%20Look%20and%20Feel)

Comment: I'm under linux and I mentioned GTK+ just as an example and changing to other LAFs (Motif,Nimbus,...) has same problem

Comment: Does your Linux System has GTK+ 2.2 or later installed?

Comment: Yes, I got the list of available LAFs in program and I'm changing to them.